# Creating client logos and buildings

Tags: building

My colleague and I are looking to give our smaller customers a custom built company logo out of LEGO, and our 3 largest customers a model of their entire building. Can you give us some pointers on where to start? Any tips?

Comment: This is an English language Stack. I was able to translate your post but other readers may not be able to. Please edit this question to English, you can copy and paste through Google Translate or another translation website.

Comment: This post feels like a minimally covered attempt to promote your website. I have edited it to remove the obvious links that do not add to the content of the post.

Answer (score 3):

I am writing an answer as though the question were posted in English, though as originally posted it is in Dutch.

The intent when making a model is to capture the important features in a way that the model strongly reminds people of the original. Buildings have features such as overall shape, colored/tinted glass, and concrete or steel columns and beams that can be replicated in a model. Exact adherence to scale is less important, especially as you probably don't want to spend a fortune on these model buildings.

Further tips, in no particular order:

- Studying some of Lego's [Architecture](https://brickset.com/sets?query=architect) series can give you some ideas.
- Use photographs or Google Street View while building as a reference to important features.
- If you have measurements of the building you can approximate a scale, say 1 stud = 10 feet.
- 3d modeling software might help but is likely overkill for this purpose.

Comment: LEGO specific 3D modeling software might be the way moving forward here. It offers a wide range of elements and allows you to explore different options without having a need for all those specific bricks you don't have.